# Local variable not being recognized inside for loop - Javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I'm trying to reference a variable inside this for loop, but its not working. It recognizes the first variable in the line but anything beyond that it won't recognize

```
        var farmsArray = Object.keys(farmsPath);
        var farmsList = new MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle("Available Farms")
            .setDescription("Where would you like to plant?")
            .setColor(0xFFF00);


        for(i=0; farmsArray[i] != undefined; i++){
            console.log(i);
            farmsList.addField(` ${farmsPath.farmsArray[i].name}`, farmsPath.farmsArray[i].size);
                 it recognizes this^          ^ but not this
        };
```

Can someone help me find out why? I've been trying for a while now and I can't seem to figure out the issue.

Comment: Did you mean  `farmsPath[farmsArray[i]].name`?

Comment: Don't use `farmsArray[i] != undefined` as the loop condition, use `i < farmsArray.length`, and don't forget to declare `var i=0` in the loop.

Comment: Btw, why do you use `Object.keys` here at all? Just write `for (const key in farmsPath) farmsList.addField(farmsPath[key].name, farmsPath[key].size)` or `for (const fp of Object.values(farmsPath)) farmsList.addField(fp.name, fp.size)`

Answer (score 0):

Based on `var farmsArray = Object.keys(farmsPath);` I'll imagine `farmsPath` is an object whose keys you want to iterate over.

```
var farmsList = new MessageEmbed()
  .setTitle("Available Farms")
  .setDescription("Where would you like to plant?")
  .setColor(0xfff00);

Object.keys(farmsPath).forEach((key) => {
  farmsList.addField(
    ` ${farmsPath[key].name}`,
    farmsPath[key].size,
  );
});
```

could be closer to what you're looking for.